# Java Runtime errors

Tags: java, compiler-errors, runtime-error

Please anyone Help me in solving this error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    schemes cannot be resolved to a variable
    schemes cannot be resolved
    schemes cannot be resolved
    schemes cannot be resolved to a variable
at org.jvnet.substance.utils.SubstanceColorSchemeUtilities.getColorSchemes(SubstanceColorSchemeUtilities.java:615)
at org.jvnet.substance.api.SubstanceSkin.getColorSchemes(SubstanceSkin.java:635)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Looks like you have only partly (re)compiled your source code. Delete all your compiled `*.class` files and recompile everything. Make sure that you don't mix old and new class files.

Comment: I had executable jar file, which i decompiled it using jd-gui, While executing i got this error. How to recompiled?

Comment: @user3008227: Please add the details to the question.

Answer (score 3):

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: schemes cannot be resolved to a variable schemes cannot be resolved schemes cannot be resolved schemes cannot be resolved to a variable

This shows that basically you shouldn't be even trying to run the code yet - it doesn't compile. If you're using Eclipse, you should have received a warning dialog when you tried to run the code, explaining that it didn't compile cleanly - at that point the right thing to do is pretty much *always* to not run it. If you're using a different IDE it may not have popped up a dialog box, but you should still be able to see an error in whatever error list view is available.

Within the `getColorSchemes` method, you're trying to refer to a variable called `schemes` which apparently hasn't been declared anywhere. We can't say any more than that without seeing the code, but it may well be as simple as there being a variable called `colorSchemes` instead of `schemes`, or something similar.

Comment: show error at this line "schemes = new ArrayList();"